# How to prevent Service Fabric autostart?

Tags: windows-10, startup, azure-service-fabric

After installing the new version 6.4.644.9590 of Service Fabric on a Windows 10 development system, using the OneNode configuration, the Service Fabric Host always  starts at system startup. The "Service Fabric Host Service" itself has a "Startup Type" setting of "Manual", but it is ignored.

I want it to only start when needed, since it's applications require other components to start before, and are quite resource consuming.

**Edit**

I found one option, to prevent immediate start, by setting the nearby Service Fabric Installer Service to manual. It seems like it checks for updates (?) and by this always starts Service Fabric. Not sure if this is the official way, seems more like a bug/limitation with the SF installer service.

Comment: Have you tried to `stop` the cluster using Service Fabric Local Cluster Manager? I have tried this on my machine and when the cluster is stopped the service isn't started automatically.

Comment: Yes, but it didn't keep the service fabric from starting with my system startup.

Comment: Sorry if I just didn’t get it but are you talking about starting the cluster with system startup or starting a service fabric cluster manager with system startup?

Comment: I want Service Fabric itself not to start automatically on system startup. The tray utility is not so much of a problem.